# Highcharts - not able to resize onclick a button in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have a Highcharts in angular 6,its working fine but whenever I click a button I want to resize/increase its width by adding class.The div got increased but chart is not increasing.I have tried reflow and window resize property but its not resolved.Can anyone please help me.here is the code below.

### app.component.html

```
<button (click)="change()">change</button>
<div [ngClass]="{'old': toggle, 'new': !toggle}" class="old" id="chart1"></div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
declare var require: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements ResultPageInterface{
  title = 'projectchart';
  toggle:boolean = true;
  change(){
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  }
  ngOnInit(){
  this.chartFunc('chart1');
  }
chartFunc(chartId){
  Highcharts.chart(chartId,{
   chart: {
         type: "spline"
      },
      title: {
         text: "Monthly Average Temperature"
      },

      series: [
         {
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
         }
      ]
   });
}

}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "projectchart",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce it in an online code editor like codesandbox? You can use it as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4

Answer (score 0):

Look; resizing div container of chart won't always resize the chart itself.

try my solution:

- Declare chart as component variable:

  `chartElement: Highcharts.Chart;`
- Use chart module to create your chart.

  `import { chart } from 'highcharts';
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
     // 
     this.chart = chart(chartId, {chart: {}...})
  }`
- Use `this.chart.redraw()` function to resize the chart.

Comment: Getting lots of error,is it possible the same thing into above code